Polars: zscore with grouping on multiple period
what is the best way with polars to calculate the zscore on multiple fields and perioid with a grouping.
I have the code below but checking if I can do something better:
window = "30d" # would like to do it on a list
df = (
    df.sort(["date", "matu", "strike"])
    .rolling(index_column="date", period=window, group_by=["matu", "strike"])
    .agg(
        [
            pl.col(col).mean().alias(f"mean {col} {window}")
            for col in ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
        ]
        + [
            pl.col(col).std().alias(f"std {col} {window}")
            for col in ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
        ]
        + [pl.col(col).first() for col in ["value1", "value2", "value3"]]
    )
    .with_columns(
        (
            (pl.col(f"{col}") - pl.col(f"mean {col} {window}"))
            / pl.col(f"std {col} {window}")
        ).alias(f"z-score {col} {window}")
        for col, window in intertools.product(
            ["value1", "value2", "value3"], [window]
        )
    )
)


The equivalent of pandas groupby + transform in polars is using window functions (pl.col(...).over()). This allows you to do things like pl.col("value") - pl.col("value").rolling_mean(...).over(...) in one go too as the latter expression (mean) will broadcast to full length.
To simplify your value looping code a little bit you can polars regex (multi-column expressions). Finally you can use .name.suffix(...) to simplify output naming.
Putting those together you can do:
result_2 = (
    df.lazy()
    .sort("date", "strike", "maturity").set_sorted("date")
    .with_columns(
        (
                (pl.col("^value.*$") - pl.col("^value.*$").rolling_mean(window_size="30d",
                                                                        by="date",
                                                                        min_periods=1))
                / pl.col("^value.*$").rolling_std(window_size="30d", by="date", min_periods=1)
        ).over(["strike", "maturity"]).name.suffix("_zscore")
    )
    .select("date", "maturity", "strike", pl.col("^*zscore*$"))
    .collect()
)

If you want to do this over many windows, I'd recommend:

put the rolling z-score expression as a function (parametrised by window and taking any input expression/multi-expression as argument)
apply this function to pl.col("^value.*$"), for every window, and suffix each with the value of the window applied.

It'll be readable and will all run in parallel this way too.

Edit: for example:
def rolling_zscore(expr: pl.Expr, window_size: str, by: str, **kwargs) -> pl.Expr:
    return (
            (expr - expr.rolling_mean(window_size=window_size, by=by, **kwargs))
            / expr.rolling_std(window_size=window_size, by=by, **kwargs)
    )


result_2 = (
    df.lazy()
    .sort("date", "strike", "maturity").set_sorted("date")
    .with_columns(
        rolling_zscore(pl.col("^value.*$"), window_size=window_size, by="date", min_periods=1)
        .over(["strike", "maturity"]).name.suffix(f"_{window_size}_zscore")

        for window_size in ("30d", "90d")
    )
    .select("date", "maturity", "strike", pl.col("^*zscore*$"))
    .collect()
)

That will give you as many columns as number of values x number of desired windows.

thanks! My values_* have some nulls so the rolling_* are not working and Polars tells me to use .rolling()...
Also what do you mean by "apply this function" if I want to run on multiple windows?

rolling_mean should support nulls no problem - perhaps you are on an old version of polars? Under 0.20+ you should certainly not run into issues and can use "min_periods" to control null handling.
I will edit my response to show you what "apply_this_function" practically means ^

@MacFly - I apologize - I actually mis-spoke. I've used rolling_mean with nulls before but not with by= as well. Running it on latest polars, recently, I also got:
Expr.rolling_*(..., by=...)' not yet supported for series with null values
This sounds like a polars issue which should be fixed soonish. In the mean time, does your data allow you to use window_size=21 instead of "30d" and drop the "by". If it is regularly spaced standard financial data you can use 21, 252 etc. for now. By operating on the .over() slice of strike and maturity you should be left with a single time series
